# Explanation Needed: How did the answer get 3.6?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, conic-sections

In Question 4(b), I am struggling to understand the reason on how the answer key got its values and why they make sense. I do understand the concepts of hyperbolas and asymptotes, however, I do not understand how $\sqrt{10}$ or dividing plays a part. Thanks!
[image]

(b) $P$ is a point in the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{4} -\frac{y^2}{36}=1$ in the right branch of the hyperbola. From $P$, lines are drawn perpendicular to the
asymptotes. The points where the perpendiculars
meet the asymptotes are $A$ and $B$, as shown on
the diagram.
Show that the product of the lengths of the two
segments $PA$ and $PB$ is constant, and state its
value.

Question Booklet: http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/assets/scholarship/2016/93202-qbk-2016.pdf

Answer Key: http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/assets/scholarship/2016/93202-ass-2016.pdf

Top Scholar's Paper :http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/assets/scholarship/2016/93202-exp-2016-topscholar.pdf

Comment: They used the formula for the distance of a point from a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used the formula for the distance from a point to a line (which is also the perpendicular distance) to find the length of AP and AB which is where the $\sqrt{10}$ comes from.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: Can you please explain to me why |3x-y||3x+y|=36?

Comment: |3x-y||3x+y| = |(3x-y)(3x+y)| = |9x^2-y^2| = |36| = 36 by multiplying the equation of the hyperbola by 36.